# How do you make a turtle grow exponentially in NetLogo?

Tags: encoding, netlogo

so I am trying to model the spread of cancer throughout human tissue and I am wondering how to make the turtles grow and divide like actual cancer cells do?
More specific:

I am starting with one turtle in the center of the interface and i want that turtle to divide into two turtles then those turtles do the same as the first one, one splits into two two split into four and four split into 8. How do i code this?

Comment: Please kindly be more specific in what you are trying to do so people can help.

Comment: Look up `size` and `hatch` in the NetLogo dictionary, try to write some code and then come back when you have a specific question that we can help you with.

Comment: Many of the sample models in NetLogo's Models Library involve reproduction. A very simple one is Hatch Example, in the Code Examples section.